# Android Bitmap texture size imageView

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I need to detect when de bitmap is too large.
I use this code:

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

In a samsung S3 mini work great (4.4.4). But when i use it in a Samsung galaxy note 3 (5.0) returns 0.
I need this texture size to compare, if the image is bigger, reduce it else not do anything.

is there a diferent way to get the max testure size in diferrent android version or there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to let Android handle the scaling so that you don't have to do these kind of calculations on a bitmap size. This should also help you keep compatible across all your devices. Check out scale types from the android dev docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Hope it helps !

Comment: If i dont do anything, the image not shows in the imageView

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling hardwareAcceleratingin your manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```